# Unable to access a service on premises kubernetes server

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using the bitwardenrs/server:latest docker image and I followed this tutorial / repo.

The service and the pods are currently healthy and, I just can't seem to connect to the service for some reason

https://github.com/cdwv/bitwarden-k8s

This is what is being returned:

{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "error trying to reach service: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:8443: connect: connection refused",
"reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
"code": 503
}

I'm trying to access the service via the master node and this endpoint:

localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/bitwarden/services/https:bitwarden-bitwarden-k8s:443/proxy/

Comment: Consider replacing the images in your question with TEXT.

Comment: I think your service name might be `bitwarden-k8s` instead of `bitwarden-bitwarden-k8s`?

Comment: Actually, if you deployed the helm chart from the repo it shows that the hostname that the ingress rule will match is `bitwarden.example`. [here](https://github.com/cdwv/bitwarden-k8s/blob/master/chart/bitwarden-k8s/values.yaml#L56).

Comment: Maybe try `localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/bitwarden/services/https:bitwarden.example/proxy/`

Comment: I tried those and it says service not found.. Service name is bitwarden-bitwarden-k8s according to my kubernetes dashboard... Thank you very much for the assistance though, still working on it. For some reason the service is unavailable..